# Using olms to style self hosted mbtiles from openmaptiles not working

Tags: openlayers

I've downloaded a OpenStreetMap vector tiles (.mbtiles) file from openmaptiles.com and successfully hosted them using node.js with the mbtiles  and express node modules.
I want to use a style gotten from MapTiler and to add it to the vector layer I'm using olms. But it will not work as shown in the client code and the map stays white I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const expr = express()
const MBTiles = require('@mapbox/mbtiles')

var mbtiles = new MBTiles("kartenbw.mbtiles", function (err, mbtiles) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error loading mbtiles file", err)
  }
});

expr.get('/', function (req, res) {
  mbtiles.getTile(req.query.z, req.query.x, req.query.y, function (err, tile, options) {
    if (!err) {
      res.set(options)
      res.send(tile)
    } else {
      res.send(404, 'Tile rendering error: ' + err + '\n')
    }
  });
});

expr.listen(3000, function () { })
```

Client:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
      <script src="ressources/lib/ol5.3/ol.js"></script>
      <script src="ressources/lib/olms/olms.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script>
        var view = new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([9, 48]),
          zoom: 15
        });
        var vt = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
          source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
            format: new ol.format.MVT(),
            type: "vector",
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/?x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
          }),
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
          layers: [vt],
          target: "map",
          view: view
        });
   // this doesn't work
   //     fetch('components/map/style.json')
   //       .then(function (response) {
   //         return response.json();
   //       })
   //       .then(function (myJson) {
   //         olms.applyStyle(vt, myJson, "basic");
   //       });
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

[image]